# How to run docker hello world? An error occurred trying to connect

Tags: windows, windows-10, docker

I have installed docker on Windows 10, but when I trying to run it with a sample, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\kitematic>docker run hello-world
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers/create: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could b
e made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I am a Docker neophyte, so I am not overly confident in my answer, but I was having the same problem you described and here is how I solved it...

First, I'll *assume* that you have a working docker-machine, such as:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
docker    -        hyperv   Running   tcp://192.168.0.22:2376           v1.9.1
```

It took me a while to get this far, since I'm using [Hyper-V](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/) to host my Docker machine. Once you're here, though, you can use `docker-machine` to get your configuration settings:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>docker-machine config docker
--tlsverify
--tlscacert="C:\\Users\\Ken\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\ca.pem"
--tlscert="C:\\Users\\Ken\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\cert.pem"
--tlskey="C:\\Users\\Ken\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\key.pem"
-H=tcp://192.168.0.22:2376
```

To persist these parameters (so you don't have to pass them on each invocation of `docker.exe`), you can create the following environment variables (click [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) for details about the variables available):

```
set DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.0.22:2376
set DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=true
set DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\Ken\.docker\machine\certs
```

I haven't scripted all this yet, but I figure I'll create an alternative to the start.sh that comes with Docker Toolbox, since that IP address is likely to change each time you start up the virtual machine hosting Docker. NOTE: `docker-machine` has you covered here, too! After you start up your docker machine, you can use the `docker-machine env <machine>` command to set these environment variables automatically!

So, I created the following bash script to replace the start.sh script:

```
docker-machine start docker
eval "$(docker-machine.exe env docker)"
```

Obviously, you'll have to swap out my specifics for yours, but I hope this is helpful. I know that I've had an awful time finding documentation about getting this stuff to run on Windows 10.